# How to find column name that contains the highest value of a row in a csv file

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the column header after going through each row and getting the highest value from that row, how do i do it?

```
with open(filePath) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:        
            euro = int(row['Euro'])       
            usd = int(row['Usd']) 
            pound = int(row['Pound'])
            yuan= int(row['Yuan'])
            max_curr = max(euro,usd,pound,yuan)
```

[image: Example rows]

Eg. For the first row of data, i want to print the header 'Euro' as 99 is the largest value in that row

And for the second row, i want to print the header 'Usd' as 99 is the largest value in that row

Comment: It might be easier to loop through an array of the column names, and remember the highest value so far and which column you got it from as you go.

Comment: Or you could e.g. construct tuples of value, column name for all four of the currencies and then use max() on the list, specifying the value as the part to find the max of. Then you'd be left with a tuple containing the column name as well as the value.

Comment: can you post example of your CSV data?

Comment: posted csv data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `key` parameter in `max()` function:

```py
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

with open(filePath) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        # converting the row values to integers.
        row = OrderedDict((k, int(v)) for k, v in row.items())
        # getting the column name of the max value
        max_curr = max(row, key=row.get)
        print(max_curr)
```

Comment: Hmmmn...I was all ready to be impressed an not post my answer.  But this gives different output than my solution.  Maybe I don't get the question....

Comment: the output i am trying to get should be, for row 1 it prints out 'Euro'. and for row 2 it prints out 'Usd'

Comment: Simply put, he wants to get the `OrderedDict key` (column name) of the max value in the row.

Comment: @DarrenStyles and this's exactly what my code does.

Comment: I don't get the right result for this code. - with the input in my answer, I get Yuan, Yuan, Euro, Yuan with this code.

Comment: @Steve Are you using the input date from your post? if yes, here's the result `Yuan Pound Usd Yuan`

Comment: @Khalid Ali, from what I get, your second answer works, but your first does not. please remove your first answer if you agree that it doesn't work.  We don't want to leave bad answers on S.O.

Comment: Yes, that's what I get too for your second solution.  Is that what you get from your first one?  I don't.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
import csv

with open("/tmp/data.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        max = -1
        for name in reader.fieldnames:
            v = int(row[name])
            if v > max:
                max = v
                maxname = name
        print(str(max) + ' ' + maxname)
```

For input:

```
Euro,Usd,Pound,Yuan
1,2,3,4
7,2,14,8
9,23,7,12
1,2,3,4
```

It produces:

```
4 Yuan
14 Pound
23 Usd
4 Yuan
```

Of course, you don't have to print the value if you don't want to.